# Google App Script: Added a search column in the Cashier View, to overcome too many menus

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I learned from other site pages, with the example of a cashier link

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby_WfAMfU8bnlJ1r67PdkP8ka7ORPEeQSe9arpZ92e9trgdoRUAswAdpIKIWH7QnHUQ/exec?username=john1234&password=hello

I would like to add a 'product search column' because it is effective if the menu is too large. so the search field is needed.

**Kode in sheet google script code.gs**

```
const getItems = () => {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Items');
  const data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  const items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    items.push({ sku: data[i][0], description: data[i][1], price: data[i][2], imageURL: data[i][3] });
  }
  return JSON.stringify(items);
}
```

Meanwhile, this is a cut of code in the html

```
<!-- search product item -->
   <div class="content">
    <div class="search-container">
      <input
        type="text" id="nisn" placeholder="Searching products...."/>
      <button id="searchBtn" onclick="search()">Searching</button>
    </div>
    
    <!-- product items  -->
    <section id="items"></section>
   </div>
```

And finally code javaScript

```
    const displayItems = () => {
      itemsContainer = document.getElementById('items');
      const items = Items.getItems();

      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const itemProduct = document.createElement('div');

        itemProduct.classList.add('item');

        itemProduct.innerHTML = `
          <img src=${items[i].imageURL} alt=${items[i].description}></img>
          <div class="info">
            <p>${items[i].description}</p>
            <p>${toDollars(items[i].price)}</p>
          </div>        `;

        itemProduct.addEventListener('click', () => {
          Order.addItem(items[i].sku);
          displayOrder();
        });

        itemsContainer.appendChild(itemProduct);
      }
    };

    const displayOrder = () => {
      const itemsTable = document.querySelector('#invoice .order .items-table');
      const order = Order.getItems();

      itemsTable.innerHTML = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        const itemLine = document.createElement('tr');

        const description = document.createElement('td');
        description.textContent = order[i].item.description;

        const quantity = document.createElement('td');
        const quantityInput = document.createElement('input');

        quantityInput.type = 'number';
        quantityInput.min = 1;
        quantityInput.value = order[i].quantity;

        quantity.appendChild(quantityInput);

        const price = document.createElement('td');
        price.textContent = toDollars(order[i].item.price);

        const subtotal = document.createElement('td');
        subtotal.textContent = toDollars(order[i].item.price * ## `Heading` ##order[i].quantity);

        // Update prices when quantity input changes
        quantityInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
          Order.updateItemQuantity(order[i].item.sku, quantityInput.value);
          quantityInput.value = order[i].quantity;
          subtotal.textContent = toDollars(order[i].item.price * order[i].quantity);
          displayTotalPrice();
        });

        const deleteItem = document.createElement('td');
        const deleteItemBtn = document.createElement('button');

        deleteItemBtn.type = 'button';
        deleteItemBtn.classList.add('delete-item-btn');
        deleteItemBtn.textContent = 'X';
        deleteItemBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          Order.removeItem(order[i].item.sku);
          displayOrder();
        });

        deleteItem.appendChild(deleteItemBtn);

        itemLine.appendChild(description);
        itemLine.appendChild(quantity);
        itemLine.appendChild(price);
        itemLine.appendChild(subtotal);
        itemLine.appendChild(deleteItem);

        itemsTable.appendChild(itemLine);
      }

      displayTotalPrice();
    };
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: It seems like you already have a search. What's the problem?

Comment: Not perfect/not as expected. When searching, you cannot click to checkout basket, the design is also a table. I'm an amateur programmer :(

Comment: I cannot see searchStudent function. And since some of the text is not in English, it’s hard to get contextual information from it for me.

Comment: Here original code, please check link https://playcode.io/1683835

And code google (code.gs)

`const getItems = () => {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Items');
  const data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();

  const items = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    items.push({
      sku: data[i][0],
      description: data[i][1],
      price: data[i][2],
      imageURL: data[i][3]
    });
  }

  return JSON.stringify(items);
};
`

Comment: Please post the code in your question. - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Done brother, iam change edit to original code, help

Comment: I don't see  how your code works.  Please consider rereading [mcve]

Comment: i don't write code because i need help to adding 'seacrh' from this code condition, from me sample before, the code was wrong... so i need you to help re-creating code for 'search product item' from this original site code

Comment: Okay then it would  be helpful if you would provide a detail explanation of what you want the searrch to do and how you wish it to operate.

Comment: This link is an example https://prnt.sc/7UDt-03TmK_i (image marked with a red box and search button), the final result I want.

How do I add the 'code' material that I mentioned at the beginning?

Comment: I apologize but I do follow links to offsite resources.  Everything needed to answer your question must be posted in the question.

Comment: So, is my explanation enough to not give me a 'search feature' for my problem?

Comment: Well let me put it to you this way.  Your question has been view 51 times so my guess is that all of the regular volunteers on this site have viewed it and my experience is that if it were possible to give you an answer based upon the current explanation then you would already have it.  So I leave it up to you to decide.